# How to create a new sharepoint site based on a template after a new item is added to a List

Tags: c#, sharepoint-2007, workflow, sharepoint-designer

How can I create a new sharepoint site based on a template after a new item is added to a list, for example I have the the sharepoint site "A" with a list with info about projects, and the idea is that after I add a new project to that list, I need to automatically create a new sharepoint site (teamspace) for that project.

Also I want to know if it is possible to create this using a workflow or maybe if I can call the webservice(c#) with the workflow.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Ok well first you have to create a sharepoint project with visual studio
in there you can write c#

to create a site in c#

```
 SPSite topLevelSite = new SPSite("http://localhost");
 SPWeb spWebInstance = topLevelSite.OpenWeb();
 String siteTemplate = spWebInstance.WebTemplate;
 try
 {
SharePointWebInstance.Webs.Add("the name", "name", "new site added",    (UInt32)System.Globalization.CultureInfo.CurrentCulture.LCID, siteTemplate, false, false);
  }
 catch(Exception ex)
 {
  //...
 }
 finally
 {
 topLevelSite.Close();
 SharePointWebInstance.Dispose();
 }
```

just to get you started, btw you cannt use c# if you only use sharepoint designer, c# is with visual studio.

to retrieve something from a list

```
using Microsoft.SharePoint;  


class SPTest {  

public void ReadList() {  

// Use using to make sure resources are released properly  
using(SPSite oSite = new SPSite(pathToSite)) {  
using(SPWeb oWeb = oSite.AllWebs[nameOfWeb]) {   
  // Alternately you can use oSite.RootWeb if you want to access the main site  

  SPList oList = oWeb.Lists[listName];  // The display name, ie. "Calendar"  

  foreach(SPListItem oItem in oList.Items) {  
    // Access each item in the list...  
    DateTime startTime = (DateTime)oItem["Start Time"];  
    // etc....  
  }  

  }  
  }  
  }  
  }
```

just to get you started, i would recomend youtube to see how you can use sharepoint and visual studio together also, or better follow Microsoft offical course 10175A (i did)
codes above where puled from the internet not from the book.

i dont think its possible to do this with normal workflows, or with javascript despite some java code is verry powerfull with ajax etc. So you should spend the time of figuring this out within visual studio. (c# is not that hard to read, take your time)

oh i see your using 2007, its less friendly to use from a programming viewpoint, if this code doesnt work on it i think its still close the way it can be done, just check object and what you do with it, it might slightly differ.

Answer (score 0):

You may be able to do this with workflow, but I really doubt it, and at the very least it wouldn't be particularly easy.

I would suggest adding an event receiver to the list, this is what I've done on the several occasions that I've needed to follow this model, and it has been quite successful for me.

You can attach an ItemCreated (or ItemCreating if you prefer) handler to the list to create the site based on the template when an item is added to the list, and it's also an option to do any configuration of the new site (possibly based on values in the list item you just created).  You could configure it through feature stapling, but I find that less convenient, especially if you need to look into the values of the newly created item.

You can also handle the ItemUpdated (or Updating) event if editing the item on the parent list needs to affect the child list.  You could also handle ItemDeleted (or Deleting) if deleting it should delete the subsite.

Answer (score -1):

you sure you want to create so many sites ?
its not something i would recommend, i mean think of the administrative tasks you get yourself into after 2 years, such things tend to grow wild.

I think you should consider 1 site for all your projects if possible
still you could tune things with rights etc
on the positive side, people will find it more easy to find things within 1 site in general.

well just my few bucks, i had to deal with project based sits to, and i found it a nightmare.
but if you like to i wont stop you, but be sure you want too..

Comment: We actually have a lot (maybe 6+ ?) sites like this at our company.  It's generally found to be a rather appropriate model.  Often the subsites are "temporary", become obsolete, and can be deleted after a while.  When they can't, you're correct, it does start to take up a lot of space, and that does need to be addressed.  Also, this isn't really an answer to the question; it's a comment.

Comment: its a comment, i wouldnt advice such an aprouch despite you use it generally, the power of sharepoint for a company is usually sharing info, not hiding it in sites.
got my shaperpoint book back tomorow, if someone else wont answer i might then.

Comment: Oh yeah, I know that this is not the best solution,and I recommended the same solution you said(1 site for all projects) but the company wants to do it creating a new site(teamspace) for every project, so I'm trying to find a solution for this :(

Comment: @user613326 It's a perfectly appropriate *comment* to make, just not an answer.  An answer should answer the question; if you just want to say, "that's not a good idea" without also stating how it should be done then post a comment, not an answer.

Comment: ok i'm kinda newbie here sometimes i confuse the buttons here :)
see my latest answer (oh and for 2007 no you cannt do that in a workflow) unless you create a workflow using visual studio. those are way more powerfull.